# Hawtio does not show DEBUG option for Camel

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

Hawtio 1.4.17 does not show a DEBUG button option for my camel routes.

On both the Camel page and on the JMX page.

[image: Page1]

[image: Page 2]

The Hawtio page states...

```
Why does the Debug or Trace tab not appear for my Camel route?

The Debug and Trace tabs depend on the JMX MBeans provided by the Camel release you use.

the Debug tab requires at least version 2.12.x or later of your Camel library to be running
the Trace tab requires either a 2.12.x or later distro of Camel or a Fuse distro of Camel from about 2.8 or later
```

Well, I'm using 2.13.2. So why..?

[image: Version]

Can some one help me out here as to why its not shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also reported on the hawtio project here

- https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/1516

You need to select a route first, in the tree before the debug/trace and other sub tabs become active.